# Check a subkey value using a random variable and a condition. KeyError: "x"

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I'm having trouble with the dictionary code for checking the value of a subkey.

I want to get that:

- If `random_data` is a word that matches `"gender": "male"` then I want to print "Word is Male"
- If `random_data` is a word that matches `"gender": "female"`, then I want to print "Word is Female"

I think the problem is the row if `random_data == data["gender"]["male"]`, so I get the error:

```
KeyError: "gender"
```

How to fix?

```
import random

data = {

    #MALE
    "escritorio": {
        "gender": "male",
    },

    "viento": {
        "gender": "male",
    },

    #FEMALE
    "silla": {
        "gender": "female",
    },

    "mesa": {
        "gender": "female",
    },
    
}

#random key: escritorio or viento or silla or mesa
random_data =  random.choice(list(data))

if random_data == data["gender"]["male"]:
    print(random_data, ": word is Male")
else:
    print(random_data, ": word is Female")
```

Comment: What are you expecting `data["gender"]` to do?  That's not one of the words in your dictionary.  And even if it existed, it wouldn't be another dictionary containing `"male"` as a key.  You want `random_data["gender"] == "male"`.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks, but now using your code i get error:     if random_data["gender"] == "male":
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @jasonharper `random_data` is a string not a dictionary `list(<dict>)` just returns a list of keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the problem is the row `if random_data == data["gender"]["male"]`, so I get the error:
>
> ```
> KeyError: "gender"
> ```

`"gender"` is a *nested* key - i.e., it's not in `data.keys()` <sup>*`['escritorio', 'viento', 'silla', 'mesa']`*</sup>, and `"male"` is not a key anywhere at all [it's a value paired to `"gender"`]. What you want is probably something like:

```py
if data[random_data]["gender"] == "male":
    print(random_data, ": word is Male")
else:
    print(random_data, ": word is Female")
```

or, using the [ternary operator](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html#ternary-operators):

```py
print(random_data, ": word is", "Male" if data[random_data]["gender"]=="male" else "Female")
```

---

You actually don't even need conditions though - you can just have

```py
print(random_data, ": word is", data[random_data]["gender"].capitalize())
```

Comment: Thank you! I accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the value, `"gender"`, is not a dictionary containing either `"male"` or `"female"`.

This may work:

```py
if data[random_data]["gender"] == "male":
    print(f"{random_data}: word is Male")
else:
    print(f"{random_data}: word is Female")
```